# apache beam pipeline freezes with java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have very basic apache beam pipeline which runs on GCP Dataflow and reads some data from a Kafka topic, transforms it and writes it to a MySQL DB using JdbcIO. All this is done with standard readers/writers components of Apache Beam. The issue is when my pipeline starts to receive data and update to a table in DB, another process also perform update on same table for 3-4 mins and then dataflow end suffers of deadlock errors **java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction**.

It's obvious that such things happen because of simultaneous update at DB end. But even other process stops updating the table, My pipeline stuck and its not processing any data coming to the topic untill I restarted the pipeline. How we can manage things here so that pipeline don't get freeze.

for dataflow job, we have defined to use
**numWorkers : 1
maxNumWorkers : 1**

Below is code sample:

```
.apply("Process and Write to CloudSQL", JdbcIO.<KV<String, String>>write()
.withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
.create(StaticValueProvider.of("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"), dbUrl)
.withUsername(dbUsername).withPassword(dbPassword))
.withStatement("insert into test_table ....values(?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...")
.withPreparedStatementSetter(new JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<KV<String, String>>() {                         
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public void setParameters(KV<String, String> element, PreparedStatement query)
    throws SQLException {
    try {       
        //....... get element data                              
        query.setInt(1, data.set...);
        query.setString(2, data.set...);
        query.setString(3, data.set...);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Exception occured while writing to db : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
}));
```

Any suggestions would be of great help. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure why the pipeline got stuck but if the write step is stuck the read step (Kafka) will not be able to read more data (and your system backlog will increase). So the investigation should be into how to make the JdbcIO.write() transform fail the current request and retry (this might be a bug in that transform).

Comment: so you suggesting bug in JdbcIO.write() itself .. as the code in post is all I'm using and I think its using default retry mechanism